# A quick 6 line riddle

Tags: riddle

> You are right to say i'm not right
>   But you are wrong to say i'm wrong
>   You can try and become me
>   But you will struggle
>   Unless you are already me
>   Then we should scout each other out and shake hands

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are

> Left-handed

You are right to say i'm not right 
But you are wrong to say i'm wrong

> Left-handed people are not right-handed but also not wrong.

You can try and become me 
But you will struggle

> I am right-handed and would struggle to relearn the same tasks as a lefty.

Unless you are already me

> If you are already left-handed then you wouldn't need to learn.

Then we should scout each other out and shake hands

> The [Scout handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_handshake) is performed left-handed.

Comment: All correct apart from the last line so far

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, completely missed that the first time.